# How to install tree on Ubuntu without sudo right?

Tags: apt, sudo, tree

I'm using a server of my lab which I do not have sudo right.
I want to show tree of specific file, so I want to install tree via

```
apt install tree
```

or

```
snap install tree
```

but it shows error: access denied (try with sudo)

So my questions are:

1. Is it able to install tree without sudo right?
2. Is there any similar alias that can substitute tree?

Many thanks,

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: check https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42567/how-to-install-program-locally-without-sudo-privileges

Comment: @mchid I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-62-generic x86_64)

Comment: @pLumo Yes the link you provied is exactly what I need. It seems to be complicated but I will check it. Many thanks.

Comment: @PhạmVănTiến Answer below.

Comment: Imo, best option would be to ask the responsible person to install such software. I know that this is often not possible ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, create a directory to work in:

```
mkdir ~/deb
```

change to the new directory:

```
cd ~/deb
```

download tree:

```
apt download tree
```

extract the files:

```
dpkg-deb -xv ./*deb ./
```

and now you can run the tree command by using the full path:

```
~/deb/usr/bin/tree
```

This installation works fine because the dependencies are few (libc6) and because the tree command doesn't rely on any installed libs.

---

Alternatively, you could set an alias for this by adding the following line to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
alias tree="$HOME/deb/usr/bin/tree"
```

and after you save the file, don't forget to source your `~/.bashrc` file to apply the changes:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Now you should be able to run the `tree` command as you normally would.

Comment: Another alternative would be to use [this command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3455651/3393576) instead of tree.

Comment: it works for me, many thanks!

Comment: @PhạmVănTiến Awesome, if this works, don't forget to click the checkmark icon to the left to mark this as the accepted solution.

Comment: This answer solved my immediate problem (allowing me to use `tree` on a machine where I don't have sudo) and also taught me something about `apt download` + `dpkg-deb -xv` ... Very valuable, thank you @mchid